Book about King Arthur, written as a framed story by a boy who meets Arthur on the island of Avalon and Arthur tells his story in the first person
I remember listening to this story on Books on Tape in the 90s but I can't find any book that has this framing device.
I know Arthur picked three stories of his knights to tell in the story, and Gawain and the Green Knight was one of them.

Hi. You've referred to this as both a book and a story. Do you have any sense of whether it was a full length novel, a novella, or a short story?

It may well not be a book since the stories of King Arthur are folklore. I Googled to see if I could find a catalogue of Books on Tape releases but without any luck. There is a release from 2004 with King Arthur stories but not without the device of a boy meeting Arthur that you describe.

Any chance it is The Seeing Stone series? Set primarily in the March of Wales during A.D. 1199 and 1200, it features a young boy named Arthur de Caldicot who observes a secondary story in the "Seeing Stone", the early life of legendary King Arthur.  - It was 2001 (pretty close to the 90s) and had an audio book
